# Complete matrix with vectors as indices in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

Let us say that we have a matrix A1 and two vectors v1 and v2 as follow:

```
A1=zeros(5, 5);
v1=[1 2 3];
v2=[5 5 4];
```

Is there a way to replace the elements of A1 using v1 and v2 as indices one by one? i.e., insert in A1(1, 5), A1(2, 5), and in A1(3, 4) some elements.

The following do all combinations of v1 and v2. I want only one by one. i.e., v1(1) with v2(1), v1(2) with v2(2), and so on.

```
A1(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have row and column information and need to convert them into a linear index, to index into `A1`. For this, use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) -

```
A1(sub2ind(size(A1),v1(1),v2(1))) = 12
A1(sub2ind(size(A1),v1(2),v2(2))) = 10
A1(sub2ind(size(A1),v1(3),v2(3))) = 9
```

Output -

```
A1 =

     0     0     0     0    12
     0     0     0     0    10
     0     0     0     9     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

If you have those values stored in some array, `array1`, use this  for the same result as above -

```
array1 = [12 10 9];
A1(sub2ind(size(A1),v1,v2)) = array1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your vectors into linear indices:

```
A1=zeros(5, 5);
v1=[1 2 3];
v2=[5 5 4];

ind=sub2ind(size(A1), v1, v2);
A1(ind(1))=1

A1 =

     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

etc.